# Printing each item of array in JSON format

Tags: python, arrays, json

I am very new to Python; I have taken a couple of beginner courses in the past and currently, I have thrown together a few scripts to help me with certain tasks at work (mostly related to gathering/parsing data). What I am trying to do now is take a list of user IDs (taken from a raw_input which has been put into an array) and then print a list of each of those numbers in JSON formatting. The result would have to look something like:

```
{
    "user_id": "12345",
    "name": "Bob",
    "comment": ""
}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
script_users = map(int, raw_input("Please enter your user IDs, seperated by space with no comma:  ").split())
final_users = list(set(script_users)) 

format = """ "name": "Bob", "comment": "" """
```

The idea was to use my format variable to print out a list of each User ID using that specific format. I know I need to use a loop to do this but I am not very familiar with them. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Use the `json` module to print Python data in JSON format.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Answer (score 0):

To encode JSON, you can import the JSON module and use the dump method and to decode jSON you can use the loads method, for example:

```
import json


json_data_encoding = json.dumps(
        {'user_id': 1, 'name': 'bob', 'comment': 'this is a comment'}
)

print(json_data_encoding)
# output: {"name": "bob", "user_id": 1, "comment": "this is a comment"}

json_data_decoding = json.loads(json_data_encoding)
print(json_data_decoding['name'])
# output: bob
```

In order to deal to produce a list follow the code below, in which also shows how to loop through the list also:

```
list_json_data_encoding = json.dumps([
    {'user_id': 1, 'name': 'bob', 'comment': 'this is a comment'},
    {'user_id': 2, 'name': 'tom', 'comment': 'this is another comment'}
]
)

print(list_json_data_encoding)
# output: [{"name": "bob", "user_id": 1, "comment": "this is a comment"}, {"name": "tom", "user_id": 2, "comment": "this is another comment"}]

list_json_data_decoding = json.loads(list_json_data_encoding)

for json_data_decoded in list_json_data_decoding:
    print(json_data_decoded['name'])
# output1: bob
# output2: tom
```

Hope this helps.

Is this what you are looking for?

```
import json


script_users = map(str, input("Please enter your user names, seperated by space with no comma:  ").split())
users = list(set(script_users))

list_users = []
for user in users:
    list_users.append({'user_id': 1, 'name': user, 'comment': 'this is a comment'})

json_user_list_encoding = json.dumps(list_users)

print(json_user_list_encoding)
# this will return a json list where user_id will always be 1 and comment will be 'this is a comment',
# the name will change for every user inputed by a space

json_user_list_decoding = json.loads(json_user_list_encoding)

for json_user_decoded in json_user_list_decoding:
    print(json_user_decoded['name'])
# output: return the names as the where entered originally
```

Comment: Great, as a follow up: let's say a user is prompted to input names via raw_input and then those names are stored in an array. Is there a way to construct a loop to go through each one of those names and then print them each out in that JSON object? For example, let's say the user inputs "Steve, John, Ted". Is there a way for the loop to go through those names and print out {"name": "Steve", "user_id": 1, "comment": "this is a comment"}, {"name": "John", "user_id": 1, "comment": "this is a comment"}, {"name": "Ted", "user_id": 1, "comment": "this is a comment"}. Sorry if this was already shown

Comment: Is this what you are looking to achieve @user7681184, I used input as I am using python 3 as raw_input is no longer used within python 3

Comment: Thanks Chris, this makes sense.